# Unix script to find, convert and replace a value from a file

Tags: css, shell, unix, scripting, sed

I have a file which contains so many values which ends with a string `px`. I need to find all those values, multiple them with `0.43` and again write them to the file with the substring `pt` instead of `px`
How do I achieve this ??

eg string from the file:

```
 .ClassOne
 {
 margin: .35em 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 1.4em 0 .5em;
 position: relative;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.ClassTwo
{
 border: 7px solid #FFF;
 border-top-color: #000;
 position: absolute;
 right: 6px;
 top: .95em;
}
.ClassThree
{
 bottom: 5px;
 height: 1px;
 left: 1em;
 position: absolute;
 right: 2em;
}
```

To find all the values that ends with px, and convert them to points by multiplying with `0.43` and write them back to the file.
`Example: 5px = 2.15pt, -9px = -3.87pt`

How to achieve this using a single line command line in unix?? Since I am new to shell scripting, I need some help. All I know is that it can be achieved using `sed -i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` onliner, you can do like this:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/px/) {$i=$i*0.43"pt";if (i=NF) $i=$i";"}}1' file
.ClassOne
 {
margin: .35em 2.15pt;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 1.4em 0 .5em;
 position: relative;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.ClassTwo
{
border: 3.01pt solid #FFF;;
 border-top-color: #000;
 position: absolute;
right: 2.58pt;
 top: .95em;
}
.ClassThree
{
bottom: 2.15pt;
height: 0.43pt;
 left: 1em;
 position: absolute;
 right: 2em;
}
```

This takes all fields with `px` int them and multiply them by `0.43` and add `pt`
It then write data back to file.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I appreciate your reply. It works fine but it doesn't change the px to pt. Can you refine this command to add that feature as well ?? and also at few cases it appends a semi-colon as well.

Comment: Id did update the `awk` to change from `px` to `pt`.  It solution is OK click the check mark to accept it :)

Comment: it is removing the semi-colon. Could you notice that in your converted example as well ?? Any idea to fix this ??
Conversion works fine.

Comment: Ups, fixed.  Just add `;` behind the `pt`

Comment: it adds a semicolon, even to the values in the middle of the line. Could a condition be put, if that is the last character of the line '\n', then append a ';' ??
and also add a '\t' to the beginning of the line wherever this change occurs, because it is removing he indentation..

Comment: there are few fixes to be made here and there I guess .. Since this is only my requirement, I think your solution is perfect for the subject. Thanx a lot bro ! :)

Comment: I did fix it so that it only adds `;` to the correct places. `3.01pt` is printed correctly. Thanks for accepting.